# Trying to use python to read in multiple dataframes for my analysis on my dissertation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have multiple participants with 3 trials each. All my files have the same naming convention so I have used a for loop to quickly read all the files.   I need to now assign each file to its own dataframe that is easy to read and allows me work on as many as possible at a time.

currently I have

```
for p in range(participants):
    for t in range(tests):
       filename = 'P'+str(p+1)+'S'+str(t+1)+'.csv'
```

I now need to assign the files to a data frame that would have a name of df(p+1)(t+1) i.e df11,df12,df13,df21, ...df153

I will need to access multiple data frames at a time and not sure how to achieve all of these data frames in an efficient manner.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating variable variables [is a bad idea in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables). Instead, lists and dictionaries accomplish the same thing, so I would recommend storing your DataFrames in a dictionary with the naming scheme you have:

```
df_dict = {}
for p in range(participants):
    for t in range(tests):
        key_name = 'df' + str(p+1) + str(t+1)
        df_dict[key_name] = pd.read_csv('P'+str(p+1)+'S'+str(t+1)+'.csv')
```

Then you can access each DataFrame through the dictionary key: `df_dict['df11']`